# aws ses java Invalid date

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

when I use aws ses to send a email exception happened which show me that

> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException:
>   Invalid date Mon, 14 Dec 2015 02:08:56 +00:00. It must be in one of
>   the formats specified by HTTP RFC 2616 section 3.3.1 (Service:
>   AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   InvalidParameterValue; Request ID:
>   e2716096-a207-11e5-9615-8135b4d7f5f9)

follows is my code :

```
public class SESEmailUtil {

    private final String accesskey = "XXXXXXXXX";
    private final String secretkey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    private String REGION = "us-east-1";
    private Region region;

    private static AWSCredentials credentials;
    private static AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient sesClient;

    private static SESEmailUtil sesEmailUtil = null;

    private SESEmailUtil() { 
        init(accesskey, secretkey);
    };

    public void init(String accesskey, String secretkey) {
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesskey, secretkey);
        sesClient = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials);
        region = Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(REGION));
        sesClient.setRegion(region);
    }

    public static SESEmailUtil getInstance() {
        if (sesEmailUtil == null) {
            synchronized (SESEmailUtil.class) {
                return new SESEmailUtil();
            }
        } else {
            return sesEmailUtil;
        }
    }

    public void sendEmail(String sender, LinkedList<String> recipients,
            String subject, String body) {
        Destination destination = new Destination(recipients);
        try {
            Content subjectContent = new Content(subject);
            Content bodyContent = new Content(body);
            Body msgBody = new Body(bodyContent);
            Message msg = new Message(subjectContent, msgBody);

            SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest(sender,
                    destination, msg);

            SendEmailResult result = sesClient.sendEmail(request);

            System.out.println(result + "Email sent");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out
                    .println("Exception from EmailSender.java. Email not send");
        }
    }
}


public class TestSend {
    private static String sender = "";
    private static LinkedList<String> recipients = new LinkedList<String>();
    static final String BODY = "This email was sent through Amazon SES by using the AWS SDK for Java.";
    static final String SUBJECT = "Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for Java)";
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SESEmailUtil sendUtil = SESEmailUtil.getInstance();
        String receive = "qinwanghao@XXXX.com.cn";
        recipients.add(receive);
        sendUtil.sendEmail(sender, recipients, SUBJECT, BODY);
    }
}
```

The code is based on the example provided by aws.
the date Mon, 14 Dec 2015 02:08:56 +00:00 is invalid , but where can I modify the format?
wish someone can help me.THK.

Comment: Here is one of the allowed format  "Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT " I find in HTTP RFC 2616 section 3.3.1, but I don't know how to modify it

Comment: What makes me confused is that I let the code running on my colleague‘s computer , the eamil can be sent OK.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is likely with Joda-time version. In case of this error you should check your dependency tree, with maven (mvn dependency:tree). Look for any joda-time versions conflicting with one supplied by aws-sdk. To fix: add the conflicting version of joda-time to exclusions in your pom.xml (or equivalent).